# Zend Framework how to do this in order to not repeat myself

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

I have this thing that I need in multiple places:

```
public function init()
{
    $fbLogin = new Zend_Session_Namespace('fbLogin'); #Get Facebook Session
    if(!$fbLogin->user) $this->_redirect('/'); #Logout the user
}
```

These two lines:

```
    $fbLogin = new Zend_Session_Namespace('fbLogin'); #Get Facebook Session
    if(!$fbLogin->user) $this->_redirect('/'); #Logout the user
```

Whats the best way  to do it in ZendFramework?To create a plugin or? I mean I want to execute it in multiple places but If I need to edit it I want to edit it in one place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of an [Action Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.introduction) that you can call from your controllers easily.

```
<?php

class My_Helper_CheckFbLogin extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function direct(array $params = array())
    {
        // you could pass in $params as an array and use any of its values if needed

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $view    = $this->getActionController()->view;

        $fbLogin = new Zend_Session_Namespace('fbLogin'); #Get Facebook Session
        if(!$fbLogin->user) {
            $this->getActionController()
                 ->getHelper('redirector')
                 ->gotoUrl('/'); #Logout the user
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

In order to use it, you have to tell the helper broker where it will live.  Here is an example code you can put in the bootstrap to do so:

```
// Make sure the path to My_ is in your path, i.e. in the library folder
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->registerNamespace('My_');
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPrefix('My_Helper');
```

Then to use it in your controller:

```
public function preDispatch()
{
    $this->_helper->CheckFbLogin(); // redirects if not logged in
}
```

It doesn't go into much detail, but [Writing Your Own Helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.writingyourown) is helpful as well.

Comment: What's the folder structure? Controller/Action/Helper/My_Helper.php?

Comment: The project I took that example from has the structure, `library/My/Helper/CheckFbLogin.php`

Comment: Ok, thanks I will try it out, I never understood ZF folders structure :))

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Action_Exception' with message 'Method "_redirect" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()' in`

Comment: I solved this using `$this->getActionController()->getHelper('redirector')->gotoUrl('/');`

Comment: Thanks, good to know you have to use getHelper from an action helper.  I went ahead and updated the question with that new statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this check in every Controller you could even set up a baseController from which you extend instead of the default one:

```
class My_Base_Controller extends Zend_Controller_Action
{ 
    public function init()
    { ...
```

---

```
class IndexController extends My_Base_Controller
{ ...
```

Shift your `init()` into the base controller and you don't need to repeat yourself in every specific controller.

Need a varying `init()` in a specific controller?

```
class FooController extends My_Base_Controller
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        ...
```